# Get publicURL from Gatsby source based on Postgres returned id

Tags: postgresql, graphql, gatsby

I'm running Gatsby with `source-filesystem` in order to generate `publicURL` and `source-pg` to connect to postgresql database.

The following query gets ids of my files:

```
  postgres {
    allInterestingList {
      id
  }
```

In my filesystem, all images have the same `id` as of those in `allInterestingList` returns.

Therefore the following query:

```
  allFile(filter: {name: {eq: "idFromTheInterestingList"}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        publicURL
      }
    }
  }
```

I would like to return and even better to merge these two, it is possible, like?

```
  postgres {
    allInterestingList {
      id ->   allFile(filter: {name: {eq: $id}}) {
                edges {
                  node {
                   <- publicURL
                  }
                }
              }
  }
```

The output should be something along these lines:

```
{
  "data": {
    "postgres": {
      "allInterestingList": [
         id: "123",
         publicURL: "static/img.ext"
      ]
    }
}
```